# CSS Transform does not increase parent div height

Tags: css, html, webkit

I have added 2 divs One is parent and other is child.

```
<div class="parent_div">
     <div class="child_div_with_transform">
     </div>
</div>
```

I have added webkit-transform to child div. Now I want to set parent div height same as it's child div after transform. Also I want to remove the scrollbar.

You can ref. following code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sab2t/

I love to try any solution.

Comment: I do not understand what you exactly want to do. Do you want to manipulate parent item using child's rules? If so, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

add

```
.Parent 
{
display:table;  // add this to your parent
width:400px;    // as per requirement
}

.child
{
display:table-row; // add this to child
}
```

It will solve your problem. Have a look [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sab2t/3/)